# slide to the right in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to animate a div to move to the right when I click its grandchild. However I am constantly running into a problem with the timing. My doubt is that I am not using the `setTimeout` function right. Could someone kindly see if they spot an error. I would prefer if my own function worked rather than using a `jquery` function as i have no prior experience in `jquery`

```
function sendrequest(element) {
    var element=element.parentNode.parentNode;
    var i=0;

    while(i<150) {
        right=i+"%";
        myVar=setTimeout(element.style.right=right,3000);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: jQuery would be pretty easy to use with no prior experience. The documentation is quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are incrementing synchronously before calling the async `setTimeout`. Here's how it can be done:

```
var element = element.parentNode.parentNode;
var i=0, myVar;
function sendrequest(){
    if (i < 150) {
       var right = i+"%";
       element.style.right = right;
       i++;
       myVar = setTimeout(sendrequest, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a css style where you use TRANSLATE. so this would help you, rather than using setTimeOut, because it is basically system clock cycle which can give nasty results, so i would prefer that dont depend on it

simply use following format

```
    el.on('click', function(){
          document.getElementByid("#id").style = "xyz";

        })
```

and in CSS style sheet use something like this

```
         .xyz{translate-x://x position in pixels}
```

for more information please read about adding styles to elements and translate in CSS

May this help you

Comment: i dnt just need to move it to a certain position, i actually need the end user to see the animate effect as it moves away